# Keyboard lags sliding panel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

I'm stuck in keyboard issue 
I'm attaching the link below so you can watch the few seconds animation.

[Click to watch animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17G9xodQ_Z3k5yW_ygwrdn9Wqbcg0Jvqz/view?usp=sharing)

In words:
when keyboard opens and if I slide down the sliding panel. the panel animation lags and it directs collapsed means from top to bottom without any drag animation
it's been a few days I'm stuck in this issue.
I'm hiding the keyboard when my sliding panel drags

I'm using [umano sliding panel library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

here is code:

```
    sliding_layout.addPanelSlideListener(object : SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener {
        override fun onPanelSlide(panel: View?, slideOffset: Float) {
            if (slideOffset < 1.0) { //offset becomes less then 1 when starting to collapsed 
                  Utils.hideKeyboard(this@DestinationAddressActivity,panel!!)

            }
        }

        override fun onPanelStateChanged(panel: View?, previousState: SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState?, newState: SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState?) {
            if (newState == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED) {
                Utils.hideKeyboard(this@DestinationAddressActivity, etSourceAddr)
                stopStateHide()
                calculateLayoutHeight()
                etSourceAddr.isCursorVisible = false
                etDestAddr.isCursorVisible = false

                val cameraPosition = CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(selectedLatLng)
                        .zoom(mMap?.cameraPosition?.zoom!!).build()

                viewMap(cameraPosition, selectedLatLng)
            } else {
                stopStateShow()
                recyclerViewSaved.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

    })



 //sliding Panel dependency
 implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
```

Comment: are you using *compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'*

Comment: @VishalG.Gohel yes

Comment: @VishalG.Gohel how will it be resolved?

Comment: ask in github issue section maybe developer of this library can help you.